# Error on password change in firebase collections

Tags: angular, change-password, zone.js

I have the following code:

```
const password = changePasswordFrom.value.password;

this._firebaseAuth.currentUser.then(user => {     
  user?.updatePassword(password).then(() => {
    //some code
  }, error => {
    //error
  });
});
```

It is working fine but If I stay logged for more time and I try to change the password I start getting the error:
POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/setAccountInfo?key=XXX 400 (zone.js)

I can't find what is the reason for this. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I read a lot of posts and documentations on the internet and the reason for this is the login period. If the client is logged after a long time to change his password, he needs to log in again, probably because of security reasons.